# Python sending mail when script gets an exception

Tags: python, email, exception

I want to know if the following is a good way to accomplish what I want.

I have a script called `main.py`, assume it runs indefinitely and has exception handling for some exceptions. Now what I want is to send me an email when any new exception occurs that is not handled. Is there a better way than this? This is in a new file, `main_wrapper.py`

```
try:
    import main # this will start the function in main, no `if __name__` condition is present here
except Exception as e:
    send_mail(e) # send_mail is a function that will send me an email
```

Is there a better way to deal with this?

PS : I am not asking how to write the `send_mail` function. I just want to know if the `try...except` way of dealing with this is good or bad.

Thanks,
Georgia

Comment: it's ok but logging could make it  better. I can show you a quick example if needed

Answer (score 0):

this is the best way of handling this, with `try except` block.

i suggest you to change:

```
except Exception as e:
```

to

```
except BaseException as e:
```

BaseException is the root of all exceptions in python.

( in case you want to catch ALL exceptions)

if you want to do more complex stuff, just ask about it.